# Modified version of summing an array with recursion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm struggeling a bit with recursion and just solved an exercise where you have to sum up all the elements of an array.

```
function sumArr (para) {

  if (para.length === 0) {
    return 0
  }

  else {
    return para.pop() + sumArr(para)
    
  }
}
```

When invoked `sumArr ( [2,3,4] )` it returns 7, as expected. However, now I changed the function a bit

```
function sumArr (para) {

  if (para.length === 0) {
    return 0
  }

  else {
    return para.pop() - sumArr(para)
    
  }
}
```

and when invoked `sumArr ( [2,3,4] )` it returns 3, which I can't wrap my head around.

Thanks for reading or even helping me understand recursion a bit better!

Comment: Do you have to use a function to do that calculation or could you use anything in javascripts tool box? like [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for example

Comment: _The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element_ `4-(3-(2-(0))) = 3`

Comment: @fedesc she's trying to learn recursion

Comment: It works as expected for addition because it's commutative and associative. Subtraction is not associative: `(a - b) - c != a - (b - c)`

Comment: @Barmar Sure. pop() has entered a little confusion there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a string instead of a calculated value and have alook to the brackets.

```js
function sumArr(para) {
    if (para.length === 0) return 0;      

    let pop = para.pop(),
        temp = `(${pop} - ${sumArr(para)})`;

    console.log(pop, temp);
    return temp;
}

console.log(sumArr([2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays are passed by reference *and* value. Using `Array.pop` mutates the collection, which is leading to side-effects like what you see. Instead, `Array.slice` as given below will return a copy of the array without the first element:

```js
function sum(arr) {
  if (arr.length) {
    return arr[0] + sum(arr.slice(1));
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```